# Magento 1.4x tables for products

Tags: mysql, magento-1.4, entity-attribute-value

I am using magento 1.4.0.1 and I am trying to export a very large database which takes a lot of time. Is there anyway that I can get all the products in the magento database tables in the following format?

```
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------+--------+-------------+------------+
| MainCategory | SubCategory | Brand|ProductName | FullDescription | ProdID | Weight | RetailPrice | OfferPrice |
+--------------+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------+--------+-------------+------------+
```

*ProdID is the product ID.

Kindly advise please?

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if the functionality is the same in 1.4 as Magento is now on version 1.9.x, but, in later versions you have an export section under System > Import/Export > Export
From the proceeding window, you can then select Products from the drop-down and then choose which Attributes you want to export.
I have had mixed results exporting and re-importing data in this way and would always opt for a database  backup/restore to carry out tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

thanks but I seem to have found the right tables. Here's my SQL:-

```
select psku.sku,pname.value as name,pdesc.value as description,price.value as price,
dprice.value as wholesale_price,w.value as weight,
m.value as image_name 
from catalog_product_entity_varchar pname
left join catalog_product_entity psku on pname.entity_id = psku.entity_id
right join catalog_product_entity_text pdesc on psku.entity_id = pdesc.entity_id
right join catalog_product_entity_decimal price on pdesc.entity_id = price.entity_id
right join catalog_product_entity_decimal dprice on dprice.entity_id = price.entity_id
right join catalog_product_entity_varchar w on w.entity_id = dprice.entity_id
right join catalog_product_entity_media_gallery m on m.entity_id = dprice.entity_id
where 
pname.attribute_id = 96 and
psku.entity_type_id = 10 and
pdesc.attribute_id = 97 and
price.attribute_id = 99 and
dprice.attribute_id = 567 and
w.attribute_id = 964
;
```